# What is the best approach for making large number of 2d rectangles using Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

Three.JS noob here trying to do 2d visualization.

I used d3.js to make an interactive visualization involving thousands of nodes (rectangle shaped). Needless to say there were performance issues during animation because Browsers have to create an svg DOM element for every one of those 10 thousand nodes.

I wish to recreate the same visualization using WebGl in order to leverage hardware acceleration.

Now ThreeJS is a library which I have choosen because of its popularity (btw, I did look at PixiJS and its api didn't appeal to me). I am wanting to know what is the best approach to do 2d graphics in three.js.

I tried creating one `PlaneGeometry` for every rectangle. But it seems that 10 thousand Plane geometries are not the say to go (animation becomes super duper slow).

I am probably missing something. I just need to know what is the best primitive way to create 2d rectangles and still identify them uniquely so that I can interact with them once drawn.

Thanks for any help.

*EDIT: Would you guys suggest to use another library by any chance?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with looking at WebGL, but depending on what you're doing in your visualization you might need to get closer to the metal than "out of the box" threejs.

I recommend taking a look at GLSL and taking a look at how you can implement your visualization using vertex and fragment shaders. You can still use threejs for a lot of the WebGL plumbing.

The reason you'll probably need to get directly into GLSL shader work is because you want to take most of the poly manipulation logic out of javascript, at least as much as is possible. Any time you ask js to do a tight loop over tens of thousands of polys to update position, etc... you are going to struggle with CPU usage.

It is going to be *much* more performant to have js pass in data parameters to your shaders and let the vertex manipulation happen there.

Take a look here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/shaders/ for a nice shader tutorial.

Comment: I was doing it wrong. I was creating planes within the animate. And that is why it was super slow. Anyway, I have resorted to using Three.FACE3 to create squares. But definitely thanks for telling me about shaders. I have done priliminary OpenGL programming in past, and I had always wondered what shaders are. Its a topic that baffles me. I will definitely go through that tutorial you mentioned.